# potentially insecure feature 'adb shell' has not been enabled

Tags: appium, appium-android, adb

Using Appium, Whenever executing adb_shell command getting an error saying `potentially insecure feature 'adb shell' has not been enabled`

***I try running appium by command line with this `appium --relaxed-security` and it works. I try to check this link

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Based on Security server arguments documentation](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/security/index.html#security-server-args), you have to run Appium server with either `--relaxed-security` or `--allow-insecure=adb_shell` argument. The latter is recommended here if you only want to use ADB and do not need other insecure features.

> `--allow-insecure=adb_shell` will cause only the ADB shell execution feature to be enabled. This is true unless `--relaxed-security` is also used, in which case all features will still be enabled.